# AWK - removal of the same fields on the basis of the "$1"

Tags: awk

I have a file1:

```
6 
3 
6 
9 
2 
6
```

This command prints the result:

```
awk 'NR==1{a=$1};$0!=a' file1
3 
9 
2
```

Now I have file2:

```
6 1 2 3 4 5 
3 3 4 4 4 6 
6 5 2 2 5 1 
9 1 3 5 4 1 
2 5 6 4 8 5 
6 1 5 2 3 1
```

I want to do the same thing, but with file2. I want to print out the result:

```
3 3 4 4 5 6 
9 5 3 2 8 1 
2 5 6 5 3 1 
    5 4   1 
      2
```

I want to do it in awk. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWK is not really suited for what you are trying to do, since it is made for processing rows one at a time, while you are trying to shift numbers up and down between different rows. That said, this monster should do what you want:

```
awk 'NR==1{nc=NF;for(i=1;i<=nc;i++)a[i]=$i}{for(i=1;i<=nc;i++){if($i!=a[i]){v[m[i]++,i]=$i;if(m[i]>nl)nl=m[i]}}}END{for(l=0;l<nl;l++){for(i=1;i<=nc;i++){if(l<m[i]){printf("%d ", v[l,i])}else{printf("  ")}}printf("\n")}}'
```

If, on the other hand, your matrix of numbers had been transposed, this task would have been far simpler:

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i!=$1)printf(" %d",$i);printf("\n")}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The first example is almost good. Only prints unnecessary spaces before the field $1 and a blank line at the end of the file. The second example does not work.

Comment: @Tedee12345 - I have updated the first line now. If you read what I wrote, you will see that the second line is not supposed to work for your case, it would work if you swapped the rows and columns in your file (that is, transpose it).

Comment: Now the first example works. As for me it is a little complicated. Thank you.

Comment: Remember to close the question by accepting if you're no longer looking for an answer.